# Inject settings into webpack application

Tags: javascript, webpack, deployment, environment, quasar-framework

We have a webpack application (quasar) which is running in multiple environments. The application is built once, for all environments. The application is stateless (has no configuration data). When the application is served from a particular environment, it must "inherit" settings relevant to that environment.

Constraints:

- the application is stateless: the application itself has no settings, but must use the settings
- no rebuilding: the application is built once, and can not be touched

How can this be done?